# SetIcon on cordova-plugin-googlemaps throws an error on iOS and freeze the screen only the first time

Tags: ios, angular, google-maps, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to change the icon (image and size) using setIcon, On Android, it works nice but on iOS it changes but the first time I execute the code the map freeze, after that the map is not frozen anymore. When I look at Xcode console it throws this error:

```
PID: 2617, TID: 951642, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x2818e5240 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   XXXXXXXXXXXXX                       0x000000010254cf9c -[PluginMarker setIcon_:iconProperty:callbackBlock:] + 5316
5   XXXXXXXXXXXXX                       0x000000010254a04c __24-[PluginMarker setIcon:]_block_invoke + 1872
6   Foundation                          0x00000001b2695ef8 <redacted> + 16
7   Foundation                          0x00000001b25a23e0 <redacted> + 72
8   Foundation                          0x00000001b25a18c8 <redacted> + 740
9   Foundation                          0x00000001b2697c7c <redacted> + 272
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d5b6f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d5cc74 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d5fffc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 524
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d5f458 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 628
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d6ddc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107d6e7ac _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b18511b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b1853cd4 start_wqthread + 4
2019-08-09 12:44:29.304099+0200 condis-family[2617:951642] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIWebView request]
```

The Typescript code is very simple:

```js
private async _showClickedShop(marker: Marker) {
    const index = this._sortedFilteredShopsList.findIndex((shop) => shop.id === this.selectedShop.id);
    const currentMarker = this._markersArray[index];
    const isFavouriteToggle = this.isShopFavouriteShop(this.selectedShop.id);
    const iconCurrent: MarkerIcon = this.iconConfig(this.selectedShop.category, 32, 45, isFavouriteToggle);
    currentMarker.setIcon(iconCurrent);

    this.selectedShop = this._sortedFilteredShopsList[marker.get('index')]
    this.isFavouriteToggle = this.isShopFavouriteShop(this.selectedShop.id);
    const iconSelected: MarkerIcon = this.iconConfig(this.selectedShop.category, 42, 55, isFavouriteToggle);
    marker.setIcon(iconSelected);
  }

  private iconConfig(category: string, width: number, height: number, isFavorite: boolean): MarkerIcon {
    const url = isFavorite ? this._getIconMarkerFAV(category) : this._getIconMarker(category);
    return {
      url,
      size: {
        width: width,
        height: height
      }
    };
  }
```

I am not very familiar on iOS errors so I don't know how to resolve it, anyone has an idea to fix this?

If I remove the setIcon, the map is not frozen anymore so the problem is there.

Comment: It might be a bug of cordova-plugin-googlemaps. Could you create an example project that contains only maps and reproduce your issue, then share it on github public repository?